# Removing Background color in Paint.net

Tags: jpeg, image-editing, paint.net

I have a .jpg image of a text logo, it looks similar to the example image here:

[image: logo example]

I am using paint.net.

Now, I would like to change the image to .png, then I would like to remove all the white background, and make the image black text on a transparent background.

I tried the magic select tool to select the white background, and I also tried the magic select tool with the shift key pressed to select all the white by color, I tried adjusting the tolerance; but I always am ending up with either very thin white border around the black text, or if I adjust tolerance, some of the black taken away making the text skewed.

I think the problem is there are some pixels that are not pure black or pure white right around the text. Those are fading from black to white. They should fade from black to transparent.

How can I remove the white background and only end up with the black text?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this website. I don't really think there is a way in paint  https://clippingmagic.com/

Comment: @Greeso, whitch format image is saved, remember png haves many flavors and not all support transparency.

Comment: I had to remove plenty of anti-aliased white backgrounds from Adobe Stock images for my game until I discovered Pixabay, where a transparent background is the default like it should be. You either get a white halo or lose too much of the content with the wand. Try this site when forced to deal with this https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/image/remove-background.

Answer (score 85):

I used the Paint Bucket tool.

- Select the Paint Bucket
- In the Colors window click `More >>`
- Move the Opacity - Alpha slider to the left
- On the toolbar, set Flood Mode to Global and the Blend Mode (the vial/potion icon) to Overwrite
- Click on the white area.

Comment: This works to some extent, but eats up some of the "letters", so the words become thinner :(

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, it manages to remove some of the antialiasing background blending which is perfect

Comment: Works like a charm, just adjust the tolerance to what you need (5-10% usually).

Comment: In 4.0.16, there's no Overwrite option when double-clicking the layer and opening the Blending > Mode list.

Comment: This doesn't quite work all the way. For a precise tool, see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1667076/754509) containing a simple Paint.NET plugin for the job!

Answer (score 17):

Paint.net has a tool `Magic Wand` that select uni-color part, select with it and pres `del`. At the end don't forget to save as png. For blur parts you need to clear it zooming the image and use the eraser to remove manually the blurred parts

[image]

Comment: Not a good solution. This is what I tried at first. The "blurry" area should not be arazed, but rather be fading into transparent instead of white.

Comment: There is no ideal one click solution. You have to do it manually in one form or another. See the Photoshop tutorials on youtube and try to mimic them on pain.net

Comment: This worked great for me. I was even able to keep the "blurry" area just by adjusting the Tolerance.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, but below are two of the easiest ways. The end results are more or less equivalent, so try both to see which one looks better to you.

1. Use [Color to Alpha plugin](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/7767-color-to-alpha-v22-2008-12-24/) from [Tanel's Photo and Color Plugins](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/11619-tanels-photo-and-color-plugins-2012-03-05/) ([download](https://forums.getpaint.net/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=11133)).
   Start with the following parameters and experiment from there:

   - Hue = off
   - Saturation = off
   - Brightness = from 255 to 255
   - Tolerance = 128
   - Feather = 0
   - Base Opacity = 0
   - Invert Alpha = on
   - Override Original Alpha = off
2. Use [AlphaSpace plugin](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/13061-alphaspace/) ([download](https://forums.getpaint.net/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=2538)).
   Start with the following parameters and experiment from there:

   - Transparency Color = White
   - Tolerance = 125

Comment: I had problems using those plugins, so I've created one myself ([forum post](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/117652-convert-grayscale-to-alpha-variation-of-a-single-color/)) with no parameters to fiddle with. It is intended only for grayscale images though, but works flawlessly for my use case.

Comment: @Felix I suggest posting that as a full answer

Comment: @Felix - your plugin is great! It should not only be answer, but the accepted one. Converting to transparent, together with its anti aliasing. Well done.

Comment: @DannyB Thanks a bunch! I posted it here for visibility. It could drown behind other answers, since this one has already some upvotes and other similar plugins.

Comment: @Felix can you please submit an edit? Sorry I don't have paint.net on current computer.

Comment: Now it only depends on reviewers. https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1070886

Comment: Post it as an answer or try again. All depends on reviewers. Maybe you'll get others :) However, from the first glance, it does a bit seem like a drastic edit.

Comment: Posted as an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1667076/754509) now!

Answer (score 3):

This Paint.NET plugin is created specifically for the problem: [Deviation to alpha](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/117652-convert-color-deviation-to-alpha-variation-of-a-single-color/). I wrote it after struggling with this myself and finding the otherwise excellent plugins in thdoan's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1209242/754509) lacking in this regard.

The plugin calculates deviation from a single RGB color, which in your case should be solid black, and applies that deviation as alpha channel variation to a solid image of the chosen color. As a result you should see your logo perfectly extracted and blended from the white background. It works with color images and other color pairs as well, but obviously the result is much different. If you have existing alpha values in the image, you can blend the alphas together. But I don't think it is the case for this question.

---

A note on why some plugins and other approaches proposed here don't work: they rely on some sort of threshold to determine which colors to exclude. The result is almost there, but it's not enough when precision is needed. By calculating the deviation exactly and forcing a single-color image, we can easily extract objects.

Comment: Very interesting, I will give it a try

Comment: @Greeso Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

You should do the inverse approach here. Don't try to remove the anti aliasing material. Instead, simply cut the black part of the text and move it to a transparent layer.

Open the image.
Use the magic wand tool.
Click the black part of the text.
Adjust the tolerance to make sure you only grab the darker pixels.
Cut the selection, leaving a faint gray outline (the part you didn't want anyway).
Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and it will auto create a perfect size for your new image.
Paste your image.
Done.

This process took me 90 seconds with your image. Here it is:

[image]